# Java Swing Split pane view layout

Tags: java, swing, view, split, pane

Hello im implementing my firs split pane view and it doesn't seem to be working for me and i get the following output...

[image]

Here is the code.

```
//Create Album Panel
    albumPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    //Add List view
    albumList.setMinimumSize (new Dimension(150,150));
    albumPanel.add(new JScrollPane(albumList));


    //Add Text Area
    textArea.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setMinimumSize (new Dimension(150,150));
    albumPanel.add(textArea);

    //Split Pane
    JSplitPane splitpane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, albumList, textArea);

    albumPanel.add(splitpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set your `albumPanel` layout to `FlowLayout` but you try and use a `BorderLayout` constants when adding to the `JSplitPane`:

`albumPanel.add(splitpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);`

you should rather set the `albumPanel` layout to `BorderLayout` via `new BorderLayout()`

Also it is not a good idea for you to set the size of your components let the `LayoutManager`'s do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add components, the JScrollPanes that hold your list and your text area, to your JSplitPane for it to show them. And yeah as David states (1+ to him), your container that holds the JSplitPane needs to be able to let it expand, and BorderLayout would work well for this.

Also, don't add components to a container more than once. Add your components to the JScrollPanes, then add the JScrollPanes to the JSplitPane. Don't also add the components to the albumPanel container. Your code is a bit schizophrenic in this regard.

Comment: I think he did when he constructed the splitpane see the docs:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#JSplitPane%28int,%20boolean,%20java.awt.Component,%20java.awt.Component%29

Comment: Yeah you're right. His code is a bit schizophrenic in that he's adding components to JScrollPanes, then adding them to the JPanel, then adding the same components to the split pane???